# Random integer declared in onCreate

Tags: java, android, random

I am currently learning Android, I have good bases in Java.

I try to use the following code in onCreate to get a random integer (1-20):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;

}
```

And on my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int randomNumber;
```

It does not work, I get only 0 as random number.

However if I do not declare my random integer on onCreat but only in Mainactivity, it works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int randomNumber=(int)(Math.random()*20)+1;
```

Finally if I use another way to get a random number declared on the onCreate, it Works as shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int randomNumber;

....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNumber=rand.nextInt(20)+1;
    }
}
```

I do not understand why I could not declare my random in the onCreate method. With Math.random but worked with rand.nextInt Anyway, I was able to make it using other code but I would like to understand why.

OnClick method code were not shown.

Comment: Does the first onCreate method you posted belong to MainActivity?

Comment: Yes it does belong to MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the problem in your code. You are using a variable 'randomNumber' as a global variable. but in oncreate method you are creating another variable with the same name 'randomNumber'. That means random number which you are obtaining is actually stored in local variable rather in global variable. And for your question

```
It does not work, I get only 0 as random number.
```

This is happening because global int variable is not local variable but instance variable by default instance variable is initialized with 0.
I hope I answer the question.

Comment: "because global int variable is by default initialized with 0" That doesn't sound right.

Comment: yeah you are right I have edited my answer. Thanks to rectify me

Comment: Still, how is a primitive variable initiliazed "by default"? It's null, not 0.

Comment: if a primitive variable is an instance of the class then primitive variable are initialized automatically with default values
int with 0
boolean with false
String with null
You cann try those as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works if I do not declare integer randomNumber in the onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    randomNumber = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;
}
```

Thanks for your help!